Generated distribution after deployment
Let$\mathcal{D}$ denote a joint distribution over the product space $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$, where $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ denote the input and output soace respectively.
Suppose that $h$ is the output of some learning rule trained on a sample $S \sim \mathcal{D}^m $. What is the resulting new distribution over $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ where now the labeling depends on $h$? How can we regurously define this distribution?
My attempt:
I would define the resulting distribution $\mathcal{D}_h$:
$$\mathcal{D}_h(\langle x ,y \rangle) = \mathcal{D}_{\mathcal{X}}(x) \times \mathcal{D}(h(x) = y|x)  $$
But what if $h$ is random, meaning $h$ use some stochastic process ( toss a coin) before giving the output? and what if $h$ is a density? If $h$ is a density distribution over the simplex $\Delta_\mathcal{Y}$, does the expression simply becomes $\mathcal{D}_h(\langle x ,y \rangle) = \mathcal{D}_{\mathcal{X}}(x) \times h^y(x)  $? where $h^y(x)$ is the probability density.
In particular, does it make sense to preserve the same marginal distribution $\mathcal{D}_{\mathcal{X}}$?
